# Average call volumes between times , total for months

Tags: sql, firebird

Table Calls c

```
CALL_ID  |  CALL_START          | CONTACT_ID | CALL_TYPE
--------------------------------------------------
2        |  25/11/2010 11:28:16 | 850        | I        
3        |  25/11/2010 11:28:57 | 850        | I        
5        |  29/11/2010 10:18:44 | 848        | I
```

Table Contacts ct

```
CONTACT_ID | COMPANY_ID | RECORD_STATUS
-----------------------------------
1          | 1          | A            
19         | 2          | A            
20         | 3          | A            
21         | 4          | A            
22         | 5          | A
```

I want to extract the number of Incoming and Outgoing calls per month
For one particular Company_id and for all the others.

I also need to have the average number of calls between 0700 and 1500 / 1500 and 2200 / 2200 0700

All starts from October 2016 and I have a list of operator's ID to include...

```
select
  extract(year from c.call_start) as MyYear,
  extract(month from c.call_start) as MyMonth,
  count(case when call_type='I' and ct.Company_id not like 391 then 1 else null end) as Incoming_Main, 
  count(case when call_type='O' and ct.Company_id not like 391 then 1 else null end) as Outgoing_Main,
  count(case when call_type='I' and ct.Company_id = 391        then 1 else null end) as Incoming_SMG,
  count(case when call_type='O' and ct.Company_id = 391        then 1 else null end) as Outgoing_SMG,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(c.CALL_START AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:00:00' and '15:00:00' and ct.company_id=391 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/31 Am391,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(c.CALL_START AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:00:00' and '15:00:00' and ct.company_id not like 391 ELSE 0 END)/31 AmMAIN,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(c.CALL_START AS TIME) BETWEEN '15:00:00' and '22:00:00' and ct.company_id =391 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/31 PM391,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(c.CALL_START AS TIME) BETWEEN '15:00:00' and '22:00:00' and ct.company_id=391 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/31 PmMAIN,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(c.CALL_START AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:00:00' and '15:00:00' and ct.company_id=391 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/31 Am391,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(c.CALL_START AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:00:00' and '15:00:00' and ct.company_id=391 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/31 Am391,
from
  CALLS c 
  left outer join CONTACTS ct on c.CONTACT_ID= ct.CONTACT_ID

where ct.RECORD_STATUS='A' 
  and c.OPERATOR_ID in (1,19,22)
  and c.call_start >='2016/10/01
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What are you stuck on? SO Is not a free coding service.

Comment: Hi Mark, not asking for free coding service ;)

Comment: Forgot to ask.... I get 0 results in times between 22:00 and 0700 where I know there are values there. Trying to workout where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Edit your question, provide sample data, expected results based on that sample and actual results. Note that your query is not asking for results between 22:00 and 07:00.

Comment: Please **edit** your question with details, don't add information pertinent to the question in the comments. Note that you need to check 00:00 - 07:00 and 22:00 - 23:59 instead (or NOT between 07:00 and 22:00).

Comment: Did the edit... seems like it would work this way. Would prefer to have 1 value between 22 and 0700

Comment: FYI: Working away with my little laptop and miss my 2 other screens LOL

Comment: move the condition `ct.RECORD_STATUS='A' ` to the `join` clause.